# How to resolve remote bundle context pax.exam error?

Tags: java, integration-testing, pax-exam

I'm trying to run some integration tests but the test failed due to a pax.exam error.

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the remote bundle context
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.getRemoteBundleContext(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:255)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.waitForState(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:211)
    at org.wso2.carbon.container.CarbonTestContainer.waitForState(CarbonTestContainer.java:401)
    at org.wso2.carbon.container.CarbonTestContainer.start(CarbonTestContainer.java:172)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.setUp(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:86)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.beforeClass(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:136)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.ReactorManager.beforeClass(ReactorManager.java:457)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.testng.listener.PaxExam.runByDriver(PaxExam.java:443)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.testng.listener.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:308)
Caused by: java.rmi.NotBoundException: 911190c4-b901-4423-b884-a9149c17575e
```

I tried to resolve by adding `pax-exam-container-rbc` dependency but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

JDK version: jdk1.8.0_311

Pax Exam version 4.13.1

Thanks in advance.